# Display the list of people who is not present today from mysql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to display the list of people who have

**Case 1:**

Forgotton to check-in and are present

**Case 2:**

Who are absent today and can't check-in today.

In both cases,check-in will be null because both have not checked-in

This is what I have achieved so far

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.`firstname` AS 'Firstname',
    u.`lastname` AS 'Lastname',
    ulr.leave_status AS 'Leave Status',
    ulr.leave_from AS 'Leave From',
    ulr.leave_to AS 'Leave To',
    ulr.leave_description AS 'Leave Description',
    DATE_FORMAT(
        ulr.leave_from,
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ) AS 'Today''s Date'
FROM
    users u
INNER JOIN users_leave_request ulr ON u.id = ulr.user_id
INNER JOIN checkin_checkout cc ON u.id = cc.users_id
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(
        leave_from,
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ) = CURDATE()
AND cc.checkin_time IS NULL
```

`users_leave_request` table: [table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UeJA.jpg)

`checkin_checkout` table: [table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxn0G.jpg)

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected output

Comment: Users thay forgot to checkin and are present don't have record in users_leave_request or I'm wrong?

Comment: you are right @krasipenkov..

Answer (score 0):

This query will select all users that didn't checkin for today and if they had record in `users_leave_request` the data for that records will also be returned.
By using `LEFT JOIN` we avoid returning empty result for not checked-in user who don't have entry in `users_leave_request`. If we use `JOIN`, result will be returned only if records are found in both `users` and `users_leave_request` tables.

```
SELECT
 u.id,
 u.`firstname` AS 'Firstname',
 u.`lastname` AS 'Lastname',
 ulr.leave_status AS 'Leave Status',
 ulr.leave_from AS 'Leave From',
 ulr.leave_to AS 'Leave To',
 ulr.leave_description AS 'Leave Description',
 DATE_FORMAT(
    ulr.leave_from,
    '%Y-%m-%d'
 ) AS 'Today''s Date'
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN users_leave_request ulr ON u.id = ulr.user_id
WHERE u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM
        users u
    INNER JOIN checkin_checkout cc ON u.id = cc.users_id
    WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(cc.checkin_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()    
)
```